# Cola de llamadas en Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, phonegap

Tengo que llamar varias veces a un servidor para que me devuelva datos en `Json`, para ello estoy usando `Ajax` con `PhoneGap`

Mi función es esta:

```
function obtenerMaestros(token, entidad) {

    var data = {
        "company": "XXXXX", "entity": entidad
    };
    var options = {
        type: 'POST',
        url: MAESTROS,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json;",
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": token
        },

        success: function (data) {
            var respuesta = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(options));


        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    }
    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {

    });

}
```

el parametro de la función `entidad` es un `array` de `String`.
A la función la llamo de la siguiente forma

```
 for (x = 0; x < entidades.length; x++)
  obtenerMaestros(token, entidades[x]);
```

Esto no me funciona, el `server` me dice que falta el token, aunque estoy seguro que se lo estoy mandando.
¿que estoy haciendo mal?

¿Cómo puedo hacer una cola de llamadas a un servidor para que cuando acabe una llamada empiece otra?

Comment: ¿ Esta el token en el formato esperado ? ¿ Estás usando JWT ?

Comment: Si en la aplicacion postman una petición sin el bucle te funciona, añade dentro del for un while que detecte si una variable global esta true o false, esta variable es false si aun no se ha recivido respuesta y true si el .done se ha ejecutado, de esta manera cada petición se vuelve async=false

Comment: @Juanjo he usado postman para comprobar que los datos que mando estan bien y el servidor responde correctamente

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de `token`? Quizás necesites ponerle el prefijo `Basic` o `Bearer`.